# How to return last added id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My controller code for adding data using laravel is given below. `$request` is globally declared

```
public function createEnquiry(Request $request){
    //my table is enquirydetails
    DB::table('enquirydetails')->insert(
        ['name' =>$request->input('name'),
        'address' =>$request->input('address') ,
        'phone' =>$request->input('phone') ,
        'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ,
        'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ]); 
}
```

I need to return the id after it added to db. This code is a Lumen `api` db insertion code. Web path is

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'Enquiry','namespace' => 'Enquiry'], 
function($router){
    $router->post('new','EnquiryController@createEnquiry');
});
```

Comment: You can get it using `return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'last_insert_id' => $data->id), 200`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `insertGetId` method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID:

```
$id = DB::table('tableName')->insertGetId(
          ['name' => $request->input('name'),
           'address'=> $request->input('address')]
);
print_r($id);
```

for more details read [Manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

Comment: instead of print_r($id) we can use " return response()->json($id);"

Answer (score 1):

First you should create a Model for your `enquirydetails` table. It could be like this:

`EnquiryDetail.php` - Model

And when doing the insertion, you can just easily do this

```
$detail = EnquiryDetail::create([
    'name' =>$request->input('name'),
    'address' =>$request->input('address') ,
    'phone' =>$request->input('phone') ,
    'created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ,
    'updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
]);
```

If it's successful, you can already access the newly inserted id like this:
`$detail->id`

Answer (score 0):

please assign `Db::` to a variable example `$result`,
then print it

```
print_r($result);
```